# CPAN on Ubuntu Can't locate local/lib.pm

Tags: perl, ubuntu-16.04, cpan

I just set up an Ubuntu 16.04 box and am trying to get some Perl modules installed.  I launched CPAN, and it went through the automatic config procedure.  At the end it dumped a few questionable messages:

```
Couldn't untar local-lib-2.000019.tar: 'Cannot allocate memory'
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  HAARG/local-lib-2.000019.tar.gz
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@INC contains: /home/steve/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /home/steve/waternow) at /usr/share/perl/5.22/CPAN/FirstTime.pm line 1347.
```

When I restarted it, it came up with the CPAN shell command line like nothing is wrong.  Did it get configured correctly, or is there something else I need to do?  I'm not a Lunix noob but not an expert either.

Also are there any better options for installing Perl modules on Ubuntu besides CPAN (for example like Activestate Perl Package Manager on Windows)?  I've never been too fond of CPAN because of experiences like this.

Comment: I'd start by checking that TMPDIR points to somewhere you have permission to write and on which there's free space

Comment: `Cannot allocate memory` sounds like you're running out of RAM. You could try `cpanm` instead.

Comment: (cpanm can be found at https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus#installation)

Comment: @melpomene that's a good bet.  I discovered the box only has 1gb.  I'm going to get some more, but might give this a try anyway.  Do you know of any downside to using it vs CPAN?

Comment: @ikegami when I ran cpan it gave options for the auto config of local::lib, sudo, and manual.  I took local::lib because it was the default.  Maybe I should have used sudo?

Comment: No downside for normal use. AFAIK it doesn't have any integration with cpantesters like https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Reporter provides for cpan, only a separate script, but that doesn't affect most people.